# How can i drive the joints of the pr2 arm manually?

Tags: microcontroller, joint, action, pr2, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

what we want to do is drive the angles of the arm joints of the pr2 manually. They are computet continously in a motion planning algorithm and send to the arm joints.

So far I have looked at: (cant post working links)

1. Moving the arm using the Joint Trajectory Action tutorial   @ wiki.ros.org/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving%20the%20arm%20using%20the%20Joint%20Trajectory%20Action

Here I have to specify waypoints for the joints over time. It does not work when I try to run it with one single waypoint. Is this somehow possible?
2. Adapt the Moving the torso tutorial @ wiki.ros.org/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving%20the%

This one is using the SingleJointPositionAction. I cant make it work because there is no action node related to r_arm_controller running on my gazebo simulator. (see section 1.5 of tutorial) Does driving the head joint differs from driving the arm joint?

3. Writing my own low level controller? See this tutorial @ wiki.ros.org/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller

Is this a good idea? I cant imagine this is the best way to do it.

I have been working with ros for just two weeks so please dont assume deep knowledge in your answers!

Any help is welcome!

Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188617/how-can-i-drive-the-joints-of-the-pr2-arm-manually?/) by [Ardu Ino](https://answers.ros.org/users/19902/ardu-ino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote this several years ago, so I don't remember how most of it works, but I think it's doing the same thing you're trying to do. Most of the message types, structure and topics should apply in both Python and C++: https://github.com/ahendrix/pr2_photoshoot/blob/master/pr2_pose/scripts/pose.py

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0